# "Accuse as" in comparison to "accuse of"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I stumbled upon this sentence:

> I **accuse myself and others as** having been irrational in the way we have been using statistics on a key notion of rationality.

Is there a difference in meaning/usage between "accuse X as" and "accuse X of"? Are they used in different contexts? Intuitively I prefer "accuse X of" every time.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference. I wouldn't use "accuse X **as** irrational" here either but "accuse X **of being** irrational". There may be a dialect where "as" is normal, though. It's really hard to make absolutist statements about usage when so many people use the language and so many are convinced that because they're native speakers, their usage is always correct, except for those obvious moments when even perfect knowledge of one's own idiolect fails and one misspeaks. That's a failing of many a politician, I've noticed, especially over the past 12 months.

Comment: There's certainly a difference in usage *statistics*. Google Books [accused as](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22accused+as%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):468K hits, [accused of](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22accused+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):11,400K hits. Using "as" in contexts where "of" would be valid conveys nothing to me apart from an indication of possible illiteracy. But it's fine in constructions like ["stand accused as a {thief}"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stand+accused+as+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example.

Comment: Just came across this for the first time: https://www.dmarge.com/2020/11/provocative-poll-ferrari-lamborghini-italian-supercar-debate.html

Answer (score 1):

You usually *accuse [someone] **of** [some act of wrongdoing]* (e.g. *"I accuse him of bigamy"*).

Less commonly, you can *accuse [someone] **as** [some type of wrongdoer]*, a form which often involves the passive voice, in conjunction with *"stand"* (e.g. *"He stands accused **as** a bigamist"*).

Thus in OP's example, where *having been irrational* is a transgression/wrongdoing, the correct preposition is *"of"*.

Comment: How accepted is it to use "as"? I first tried to write "they accused her as a witch", but I was not sure if "accused as" is grammatically correct, so I replaced it with "they accused her of being a witch" but that phrase had to be repeated multiple times and it looked too cumbersome. "they accused her of a witch" is incorrect, right?